# Is there a way to run a test.aspx file inside a precompiled_non-updatable website

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have a large enterprise website, which was build and published as precompiled / non-updatable. Now I have an issue that is happening only at one customer site. So, I wanted to create a simple test.aspx file inside the website in question, and run it at the customer site -- without having to re-compile and publish the original website. Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Below is the error that received when I copy and try to run my test.aspx page:

> The file '/MyWebApp/test.aspx' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot
>   be requested.

Environment is: Windows 2008 R2 - 64bit OS

Answer (score -1):

re-publish entire solution but copy only the file u want and past it in IIS folder.